# What's the "Thumbs up" setting in Motorola Camera app

Tags: motorola, front-camera

I have Motorola Moto Z Play phone. **When switching to front-camera** in Camera app, there is a setting that I haven't figured out it's purpose. It has three possible options:

- Off
- Manual (shows a slider which its value can be chosen from 1 to 7).
- Auto

Here is a screenshot of this setting:

[image]

There is no reference to this setting in the official manual and I haven't found any resources that explains it. Does anybody know what's it for? There could be a similar front-camera setting for other phone brands too, but I haven't much experience about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is the [beauty mode](http://m.gsmarena.com/moto_z_droid_edition-review-1471p9.php)

> The 5MP front-facing camera adds one extra control to this menu and that is for beauty mode. There are three options: auto, manual, or off. The manual option lets you move a slider like most other smartphones that offer a beauty mode which blends the skin tones to hide imperfections

Also called [beautification mode](https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.androidauthority.com/moto-z-moto-z-force-droid-review-704717/amp/)

> We start off with self portraits, which include a Beautification mode, which is a first for Moto, but not a first for Lenovo at large. It mainly enhances clarity and colors while smoothing out lines on the face, to varying degrees of success.

*Off* would be to disable the mode, *manual* would be adjust the beauty effect and *auto* would let the camera decide

**Edit:** It's not a *thumbs up*, it is a silhouette of a female face sideways - you can see that clearly from [Lenovo feature](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht104438), with the 7 step sliding scale. Moto seems to have added auto feature in addition

Comment: Samsung, LG and maybe others have  this mode with different functionalities, but quoted Lenovo in the solution since they own Moto